# Why does my php contact form send blank responses?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple contact form. However, when the email comes through all the responses are blank.

```
<?php
$EmailFrom = "hideemail";
$EmailTo = "hideemail";
$Subject = "GrueRadio - Form Submission";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

if ($success){
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thank-you-form.html\">";
}
else{
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

```
<form style="padding-top: 70px;" method="post" action="engine.php">
    <h1 style="color: #442154;text-align: center;"><strong>Contact</strong></h1>
    <p class="faq-para" style="padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;">Need to contact the team about a DCMA, Song Request or another issue?<br>You can also contact us directly, dan@gruegamers.com.</p>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 25%;" required="" placeholder="Name" name="name"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="email" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 25%;" placeholder="Email" name="email"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control form-control-lg" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 25%;min-height: 200px;" placeholder="What are you contacting us about? Please specify with much information as possible." name="message"></textarea></div>
    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 25%;" type="submit">Submit form</button></div>
</form>
```

Would appreciate any pointers to get this working. This is what I have tried so far.

Thanks

Comment: Because you don't check if a form is submitted or do any validation at all

Comment: I see, I'm very new to PHP, what kind of validation should/could I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$_POST['key']` is case sensitive and you put capital letter on your PHP code. Your keys should match exactly with your input names.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that they had to match exactly!